# Hexadecimal floating point in fortran

Tags: fortran, floating-point-conversion

Is there an equivalent for the 'a' format specifier known from C in Fortran?

C Example:

```
printf("%a\n",43.1e6); // 0x1.48d3bp+25
```

Exporting floating point numbers in hexadecimal format prevents rounding errors. While the rounding errors are usually negligible, it is still advantageous to be able to restore a saved value exactly. Note, that the hexadecimal representation produced by printf is portable and human readable.

How can I export and parse floating point numbers in Fortran like I do in C using the 'a' specifier?

Comment: The 'Z' specifier cannot be used to import data exported with 'a'. Floats exported with 'Z' cannot be identified as floats anymore and their representation is machine specific.

Comment: There is no such descriptor . You will have to write your own output conversion.

Comment: I removed everything related to the 'Z' specifier to avoid confusion. All i want to know is the equivalent of 'a' in Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have full precision, the best way is to use unformatted files, such as this:

```
program main
  real :: r
  integer :: i
  r = -4*atan(1.)
  open(20,access="stream")
  write (20) r
  close(20)
end program main
```

(I used stream access, which is new to Fortran 2003, because
it is usually less confusing than normal unformatted access). You can then use, for example, `od -t x1 fort.20` to look at this as a hex dump.

You can also use `TRANSFER` to copy the bit pattern to an integer and then use the Z edit descriptor.

If you really want to mimic the %a specifier, you'll have to roll your own. Most machines now use IEEE format.  Use `TRANSFER` for copying the pattern to an integer, then pick that apart using `IAND` (and multiplications or divisions by powers of two for shifting).

Comment: Yes, only now I realized why the OP wants that format and it really isn't a good idea.

Comment: 1) The usefulness of '%a' lies also in the support by other applications. For example Mathematica can parse CSV files with hexadecimal floating point numbers. Importing binary data is much more difficult. 2) Portability of binary data depends also on endianness and the specific precision used. - I am looking for the exact equivalent of the 'a' format specifier and not any other way of storing floating point numbers.

Comment: @user3337813 if portability is your concern you can always use a container like netcdf, hdf, etc to store your arrays.

Comment: Well, your options are limited.  Fortran has no such descriptor.  You can a) roll your own in Fortran using bit shuffling (see above) b) roll you own using Fortran specific functions for picking apart numbers (even less difficult). c) propose to the Fortran standards committee (not very likely to succeed).  d) Extend an open-source compiler like gfortran and propose a patch to the gfortran team (much more difficult).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to let the C library do your work for you and interface via C binding.  This rather depends on a modern compiler (some F2003 features used).

```
module x
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  private
  public :: a_fmt
  interface
     subroutine doit(a, dest, n) bind(C) 
       import
       real(kind=c_double), value :: a
       character(kind=c_char), intent(out) :: dest(*)
       integer, value :: n
     end subroutine doit
  end interface

  interface a_fmt
     module procedure a_fmt_float, a_fmt_double
  end interface a_fmt

contains
  function a_fmt_float(a) result(res)
    real(kind=c_float), intent(in) :: a
    character(len=:), allocatable :: res
    res = a_fmt_double (real(a, kind=c_double))
  end function a_fmt_float

  function a_fmt_double(a) result(res)
    real(kind=c_double), intent(in) :: a
    character(len=:), allocatable :: res
    character(len=30) :: dest
    integer :: n
    call doit (a, dest, len(dest))
    n = index(dest, achar(0))
    res = dest(1:n)
  end function a_fmt_double

end module x

program main
  use x
  implicit none
  double precision :: r
  integer :: i
  r = -1./3.d0
  do i=1,1030
     print *,a_fmt(r)
     r = - r * 2.0
  end do
end program main

#include <stdio.h>

void doit (double a, char *dest, int n)
{
  snprintf(dest, n-1, "%a", a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortran 2018 standard introduced 'EX' descriptor which does exactly what '%a' in C. Recent Intel ifort compiler does support that, GNU Fortran - not yet as of version 12.2.0